# Limit draggable shape to a set div or area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to constrain a draggable shape to only be dragged over a set div or area?

I'm using jQuery.

---

Poelinca, thanks for your reply. Using the 'containment' option in the draggable parameters I managed to fix my issue.

$(".item").draggable({
                 containment: '#wrapper'
 });

Comment: by `dragged over a set of ...` do you mean dropped ?

Comment: No, I mean you should only be able to drag the shape within a set div or area. So not over the entire webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [containment option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) for the draggable widget from jQuery UI .

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region. Possible string values: 'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2].

Or you can use [axis option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-axis) to :

> Constrains dragging to either the horizontal (x) or vertical (y) axis. Possible values: 'x', 'y'.

You can find [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement) some examples.